# Jenkins configuration as code: programmatically reload configuration from file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli, jcasc

How to reload Jenkins configuration as code file from within groovy script? (Equivalent of clicking on "Reload existing configuration")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sample groovy script to reload configuration yaml file:

```
import io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode;
ConfigurationAsCode.get().configure()
```

Comment: Where do you get this type information/knowledge ?